# The regular expression for finding all the $_post['a-z'] pattern in code in php storm?

Tags: php, regex, phpstorm

I want to replace all the  `$_POST['a-z']` pattern with the `mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['a-z'])`.

So that replacement will  add `mysqli_real_escape_string(` at the start and  `)` at the end of `"]"` - leaving intact, all between this  `['']`

What will be the regular expression for doing this in php storm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search pattern: `(\$_POST\['[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+'\])`

Replacement string: `mysqli_real_escape_string($1)`

This will replace strings like `$_POST['a-z']`, `$_POST['aaa']`, `$_POST['Hello-Pink_Kitten99']`. **If you need to also match other characters -- adjust pattern as required.**

Comment: thank you so much,it saved my so much time.Thank you one again.Plz also sugessto  replace above with this    mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->connection ,$_POST['a-z'])

Comment: I tried this  to replace with mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db->connection ,$_POST['a-z']) but phpstorm generate error saying "u are refracting with malformed replacement"

Comment: As simple as `mysqli_real_escape_string(\\$this->db->connection, $1)`